# Add row manually in excel and finally update into table using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, excel

I am working on an application where I will be clicking a button on the web form to update time entry. On clicking the "Update time entry" button, an Excel file gets opened and I need to update today's time sheet details and again when saving and closing the Excel file, the details should be update in the database.

My question is how can I add another row to entering the time sheet after clicking like "+" button in the Excel? By that I can enter additional tasks on the same date.

I planned to use the following code:

```
// Load excel file.
var file = ExcelFile.Load("input.xlsx");
var sheet = file.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

// Set worksheet without grid lines.
sheet.ViewOptions.ShowGridLines = false;

// Set worksheet with protection.
sheet.Protected = true;

// Iterate through the required cells, set their borders and unlock them.
var range = sheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A1", "C" + sheet.Rows.Count);

foreach (var cell in range)
{
    cell.SetBorders(MultipleBorders.Outside, Color.Black, LineStyle.Thin);
    cell.Style.Locked = false;
}

// Save Excel file
file.Save("output.xlsx");
```

Comment: Did you intentionally tag SQL Server? Doesn't appear in your question...

Comment: To save the excel data into sql server database.

Comment: Sure, but your question says "how can I add another row to entering the time sheet" which has nothing to do with SQL Server and none of your SQL Server code is there.

Comment: yes, you are half correct. I also want to send the data from excel to sql server.

Comment: I suggest a second question in that case, including your related code.

Comment: how you bring the data to load to excel?

Comment: Using interop can open the excel. Then I need to edit and while closing the updated details should be saved into table

Comment: You can use OleDb for reading data from excel and load it to a data table then you can use this database to insert it to the database.

Comment: I want to edit in the excel itself rather reading into data table.

Comment: Is anyone having the answer, more helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have problems to use external libraries, I recommend you to use the [ClosedXml](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), that is a very simple library to work with Excel.

Comment: This is not the answer